# Официальные названия родственников

Tags: грамотная-речь

Известно, что слова "отец" и "мать" являются более официальными и отстраненными, нежели "папа" и "мама". И чаще употребляются в официальной речи. А как быть с "дедушкой" и "бабушкой"? Все-таки — *дед* и *бабка*, или формы *дедушка-бабушка* тоже допустимы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы о какой допустимости спрашиаете?  Уровень официальности, так сказать?
В Гражданском кодексе никаких бабушек я не встречал (правда насквозь его никогда не читал). Отец, мать, дед, бабка, а также дядя и тётка.

Answer (score 3):

У Ожегова: мать отца или матери - бабушка. БАбка в этом же значении дается как разговорное. В других словарях - как просторечное. С трудом представляю как бы в суде сказали: ребенок имеет право видеться с отцом и бабкой. А вот с дедушкой наоборот. Отец матери или отца - дед. А дедушка - разговорное. ласкательное.